# Using command blocks, how can I automatically place mined blocks into the inventory of the player who mined them?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to make it so that each time you mine a block, you get the block, using command blocks in MCPE? It doesn't matter what tool you use, or just your fist, it just appears in your inventory. The block doesn't drop onto the floor.